# Quartz - ClassCastException

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, quartz-scheduler, jboss5.x

I am using Jboss5.1.x , EJB3.0
I am trying to configure Quartz.
I get this exception when I try to do lookup:

```
       InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        StdScheduler scheduler = (StdScheduler) ctx.lookup("Quartz");
```

this is the exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler cannot be cast to org.quartz.Scheduler

anyone has any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely have two copies of the Quartz JAR in your classpath - JBoss has its own copy, and your application probably has one too, in its `lib` directory. The two are clashing.

Remove the JAR from your application and try again.

Comment: If ill remove the one which is in my application, IT wont be able to compile, coz I need some libraries from this jar.

Comment: @rayman: Your compilation classpath, and what gets packaged in your deployable application, are two entirely different things. Compile against whichever quartz JAR you need to, but don't package it in your WAR/EAR.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a Scheduler bound to JNDI, so you should do this:

```
 Scheduler scheduler = (Scheduler) ctx.lookup("Quartz");
```

Check that you have configured quartz correctly by following this [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/84-jboss-quartz.html?start=1).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the `quartzservice` in `jboss-service.xml` in META-INF.

```
 <module>
     <service>quartzservice.sar</service>
 </module>
```

That's it. Service is bound and can be used from within the whole EAR.

Comment: Shouldn't it be at jboss-service.xml ??