# Upgrading the quartz from 1.5.2 to 2.2.0 on JBoss 4.2.2 GA

Tags: java, jboss, quartz-scheduler

After trying around following Kariem's comments(showing how to upgrading from 1.5.2 to 1.6.0), I am also trying to upgrade Quartz Scheduler 1.5.2 to 2.2.0. The java version on the server is 1.6.

However, when I execute the scheduler after rebooting the server, it shows me the error below. I tried to change it back to 1.5.2. The error message is the same still. Does anyone know how to fix it?

17:13:58,811 ERROR [STDERR] Exception in thread "Thread-11" 
17:13:58,813 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class 
17:13:58,814 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
17:13:58,814 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632) 
17:13:58,814 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616) 
17:13:58,814 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) 
17:13:58,814 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1814) 
17:13:58,814 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:872) 
17:13:58,814 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.WebAppClassLoader.findClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:139) 
17:13:58,814 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1325) 
17:13:58,814 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)

Answer (score 0):

After few days searching, I found out the answer finally.

First, I follow the this link to configure a Quartz service on JBoss - https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureAQuartzService 
Second, make sure there is no quartz JAR in the classpath. Otherwise, you will get "Quartz - ClassCastException". Thanks for the hint from this link - [Quartz - ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873221/quartz-classcastexception)